# How do I collect all the data in column?

Tags: vb.net

i have a table like that;

```
name  surname  age
x      x        21
x      x        33
x      x        25
.
.
.
```

i want to collect all ages and write in textbox how can i do that with vb.net
P.S : my db is access 2010

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  start by showing what you have tried

Comment: i think my question is so perceptible if u dont know solution u dont have to comment!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting rows from Access database by date search criteria in VB.NET form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769768/selecting-rows-from-access-database-by-date-search-criteria-in-vb-net-form)

Comment: do u think this is my problem ? oh my god
i just want to collect ages

Comment: your question lacks sufficient info to know what your real problems are. do you know how to create a DB connection? Cant tell.  Do you know how to write a SELECT statement? Cant tell.  Do you know how to handle query results? Cant tell.  The link shows those steps.