# vb.net Query for access Where Date.now before?

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I'm trying to make a query in vb.net on OleDB, where the date is less than the current, something like this:

```
adaptadordatos = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Partidas WHERE FechaHora <'" & Date.Now() & "'", con)
```

But it is not correct because I pulled Error **OleDbException**

At DB is access

Comment: `I pulled Error OleDbException` doesnt give us anything to work with.  See [Ask]

Comment: @Plutonix My English is poor ... But it is simple what I want. As I can make a query from an earlier date?

Comment: I can tell what you want.  But we cant help without the error message.  You should also be using SQL Paramters, if the db column is a date, you are passing text

Comment: YOu need to research first, then ask -- Possible duplicate of [Selecting rows from Access database by date search criteria in VB.NET form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769768/selecting-rows-from-access-database-by-date-search-criteria-in-vb-net-form)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use sql all the way?

```
SELECT * FROM Partidas WHERE FechaHora < NOW()
```